# Technical Lemma for Central Simple Algebras?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

There is a technical lemma on slide 7 of these [slides](http://www.math.virginia.edu/~ww9c/divalgebras.pdf), but no proof.

Is there a simple proof I can read before moving on? The lemma itself says

> Let $S$ be a central simple $k$-algebra and let $R$ be an arbitrary $k$-algebra. Then every two-sided ideal $J$ of $R\otimes S$ has the form $I\otimes S$ where $I=J\cap R$ is a two-sided ideal of $R$. In particular, if $R$ is simple, then $R\otimes S$ is simple.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the first result in $\S 4$ of [these notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/noncommutativealgebra.pdf).